# Erlang OTP supervising Java application

Tags: java, erlang, monitoring, erlang-supervisor

I have recently become familiar with Erlang/OTP technology and I would like to apply it to monitor and supervise Java applications in terms of:

- detecting their availability
- starting and stopping them

In other words I would like Java applications to be seen by Erlang OTP supervisor infrastructure as a regular Erlang apps that can be managed by those supervisors (sending heartbeats, stopping and starting on demand). Is it feasible? If yes, what tools do I have to use?

For simplification, let's assume that a *Java application* is a simple jar with Main class specified. Instrumenting/extending those applications is allowed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless there's an existing Erlang application that you need to use, I'd suggest using the [Akka](http://akka.io/) library, which is greatly influenced by OTP and will let you create supervisor hierarchies using just JVMs.